# Python: translating the program

Tags: python, string

Given a string with codon letters I can´t figure what the following program is explicitly doing. I know that it goes through the whole string but what is it doing exactly ?

```
s = "AVGGGKGDEMAWTWVRPMGVIDWEEGGVKLVAGLLP"

[i for i in range(1,len(s)) if s[i] in 'VE' and s[i-1]!= 'W'] ?
```

The response is [5, 28].

Comment: If the current character is either V or E and the one before it is not W, save the index (location) of that character. Try running it again. The response I get is `[1, 8, 19, 24, 27, 30]`.

Comment: Thank You a lot ! You are right...I copy paste the wrong string... I was trying to exercise and I put a different one. You are right. That´s the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list comprehension goes through string `s` one index at a time and checks 2 conditions:

- Is the character at index `i` in the string `'VE'`?
- Is the character before the character at index `i` not equal to `'W'`?

If both those conditions are `True` then `i` is added to a new list (which in this example isn't being saved).

The output is telling you the characters at index 5 and index 28 meet these conditions (the output doesn't seem to be right for this string though). Remember strings are 0 indexed, meaning the first letter of the string is accessed via `s[0]`.

Additional info:

- [Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)
- [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Thank You a lot ! You are right...I copy paste the wrong string... I was trying to exercise and I put a different one.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider accepting it as the answer. You can this by clicking the check mark.